# how to download people's hidden/private github repositories

Tags: github

so I want to tell you that I was working in a group but the source was taken by a group of friends and uploaded on github, and now it has been hidden from me. How can I get the source from the github?

Comment: You need to talk to your friends and get them to give you access.  I doubt that Github is going to intervene to give you access without either your friends' permission ... or a court order!

Comment: And if you are asking if there is a way to get access to someone else's private repos ... in general, the answer is a resounding NO.  Private means private.

Comment: Oke thanksss sir